# jquery access dynamically generated element

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have dynamically created "td" elements and want to access them after an AJAX call. The cells have two attributes, `descriptorid` and `userid`.

```
  var userid = field["id"];
  var descriptorid = field["editrights_projection"][x];
  console.log( "userid: " + userid );                                       //Log 1
  console.log( "descriptorid: " + descriptorid );                           //Log 2
  console.log( $("td[descriptorid='333'][userid='5']") );                  //Log 3
  console.log( $("td[descriptorid='descriptorid'][userid='userid']") );    //Log 4
```

results in:

```
userid: 5                                                     //Log 1
descriptorid: 333                                             //Log 2
r.fn.init [td.cell, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]                 //Log 3
r.fn.init [prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]                          //Log 4
```

When adding the numbers manually (Log 3) i can access the cell and manipulate it, using variables (Log4) doesn't work.

**Addition:**

I've searched and read several posts, also about event delegation but using

```
$("#table").on('click', "td[descriptorid='descriptorid'][userid='userid']", function(){
    //Your code
});
```

Only works if the cell is actually clicked, which is not what i want. I want it manipulatet automatically after the call.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my problem was sourrounding the variables with `+` and `"` .

```
$("td[descriptorid='"+descriptorid+"'][userid='"+userid+"']")
```